# function expression returned instead of result

Tags: javascript, function

Hello I'm going throug script example and i don't understand result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var o = {
        d: 11,
        m: function (){ 
            var that=this;

            return function(){return that.d;}
        }
    };

    alert(typeof o.m);

    var num = o.m();
    alert(num);

    var num = o.m()();
    alert(num);

</script>
```

I thought that executing `o.m` function by `o.m();` shoud return 11 but it returns `function(){return that.d;}` when calling `o.m()();` actually returns 11.

I dont get it.

Comment: That would alert "function", the body of m then 11.  What's the problem?

Comment: this is so not the way to ask a question... :|

Comment: I can agree with that. I could've stated it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that executing o.m function by o.m(); shoud return 11 but it returns function(){return that.d;} when calling o.m()(); actually returns 11.

Functions in JavaScript are objects, just like any other object. And so the line in `m`

```
return function() { return that.d;}
```

...creates and returns a function when `m` is called. There's nothing in that line that *calls* the function it's creating.

Since `m` returns a function, when you call it, you get back the function:

```
var x = o.m();
```

`x` is now a reference to the function that was created by that call to `o.m()`. Each call to `o.m()` will create and return a *new* function.

Since `x` refers to the function, you can call it:

```
console.log(x()); // 11
```

(The reason it works is related to the fact that the function `m` creates and returns is something called a "closure" over the context of the call to `m`, and that context contains a `that` variable that `m` sets up so that it can use `that.d` in the function it returns. Going into detail here would probably get confusing, but when you're ready, don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)